# What are the KML limitations in Google Earth for Chrome (web client) compared to Google Earth Pro?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

Compared to the desktop version (aka Google Earth Pro), I noticed that the web version lacks some advanced features found in the [official Google KML references](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference), which instead work on Google Earh Pro, such as the NetworkLinkControl, the LineString styling and the ScreenOvelay.

However I can't find on the web which of the KML features are available in the web version too and which are not.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth [help article](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/7365595/import-your-kml-map-data-into-google-earth-computer?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1) states:

> You can view **most simple KML files** with *Google Earth for Chrome* (version 9) (aka Google Earth Web). If you’re unable to view complex KML files, use *Google Earth for desktop*, which **supports all KML features**.

The list has a couple of restrictions but doesn't provide details:

- Simple network links
- Simple KML tours without audio
- Some custom icons and overlay images hosted on other websites won’t work.

In addition, these KML features appear to be supported:

- GroundOverlay
- ScreenOverlay
- Regions with min/max LOD and fade extent

Google Earth Pro (supports the full KML spec for with respect to rendering, but even Google Earth Pro has some issues with respect to KML mostly in what the KML authoring tool allows as reported in the [KML Errata](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#limits).